# Dynamically creating div height in 2 rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

So I am trying to get the height of the div toolLeft to match div height of toolRight and the same with beneLeft and beneRight. Below is my code, but only get the beneLeft height to change to match beneRight. Looked at some examples on where I could be wrong, but not seeing it. On top of that, my function has gotten super bloated. What is the best approach to this?

The code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="homeHead col-md-12">
        <h2>Welcome to the Navia Banefits participant portal, {{ ppt.Ppt.firstName }}!</h2>
        <p>{{ ppt.Ppt.coName }} ({{ ppt.Ppt.coCode }})</p>
        <div class="alerts">
            <div id="example" ng-app="fpsClientApp">
                <div class="demo-section k-header">
                    <div ng-controller="pptController">
                        <div kendo-tab-strip k-content-urls="[ null, null]" id="alertTabs">
                            <!-- tab list -->
                            <ul>
                                <li class="k-state-active">special messages</li>
                                <li>outstanding swipes</li>
                                <li>recent denials</li>
                                <li>upcoming dates</li>
                                <li>account alerts</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="alertCompany">
                                <p> {{ ppt.CompanyAlert.value }} </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alertSwipes">
                                <p ng-repeat="swipes in ppt.Swipes"><span class="col-md-2">{{swipes.date|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span> <span class="col-md-9">{{date.descr}}</span></p>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="alertDenials">
                                <p ng-repeat="denials in ppt.Denials"><span class="col-md-2">{{denials.date|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span> <span class="col-md-9">{{denials.descr}}</span></p> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="alertDates">
                                <p ng-repeat="dates in ppt.Dates"><span class="col-md-2">{{dates.key|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span> <span class="col-md-9">{{dates.value}}</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alertAccounts">
                                <p ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts" ><span class="col-md-2">{{date.date|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span> <span class="col-md-9">{{date.descr}}</span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- begin Benefit Tile cards -->

    <div class="beneArea">
        <div class="beneLeft col-md-3">
            <div>
                <h2>My Benefit Statements</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Click on a benefit tile to access more detailed information.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="beneRight col-md-9">
            <div class="beneTile col-md-3" data-ng-repeat="Benefits in ppt" style="margin: 4px; margin-left: 20px;">
                <div class="beneHead">
                    <p>{{ ppt.Benefits[0].name }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="beneDetails">
                    <div class="beneText">
                        <p class="beneDesc">Current Balance</p>
                        <p class="beneMoney">{{ ppt.Benefits[0].balance }}</p>
                        <p class="beneDesc">Annual Election</p>
                        <p class="beneMoney">{{ ppt.Benefits[0].annualAmt }}</p>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="beneFooter" style="clear: both;">
                        <p><span>Last day to incur expenses:</span> <span style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">{{ ppt.Benefits[0].lastIncurDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>
                        <p><span>Last day to submit claims:</span> <span style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">{{ ppt.Benefits[0].lastSubmitDate|date : 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span></p>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end Benefit Tile cards -->

    <!-- being Tool Tile cards -->

    <div class="toolArea">
        <div class="toolLeft col-md-3">
            <div>
                <h2>My Tools</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Click on a tile to access and maintain your account.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="toolRight col-md-9">
            <div class="tools">
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submiticon.svg" >
                        <p>Submit a Claim for Reimbursement</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/commuterOrder">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/commutericon.svg" >
                        <p>GoNavia Commuter</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/accessHsa">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/hsa.svg" >
                        <p>Access my HSA</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>        
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/clearSwipe">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/clearswipe.svg" >
                        <p>Clear a Swipe</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>   
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/naviconnect.svg" >
                        <p>Access NaviConnect</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/naviapp.svg" >
                        <p>Manage My Navi App</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/formsdocs.svg" >
                        <p>Forms and Documents</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>        
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/navicommuter.svg" >
                        <p>Access my NaviCommuter</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>                   
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/requestnewcard.svg" >
                        <p>Request a new NaviCard</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/updateprofile.svg" >
                        <p>Update my Profile</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/onlineenrollment.svg" >
                        <p>Online Enrollment</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div>        
                <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
                    <a href="#/claimEnter">
                        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/recurring.svg" >
                        <p>My Recurring Claims</p>                        
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- end Tool Tile cards -->

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#alertTabs").kendoTabStrip({
            tabPosition: "left",
            animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn" } }
        });
    });

    var leftBeneHeight = $(".beneLeft").height();
    var rightBeneHeight = $(".beneRight").height();

    if (leftBeneHeight > rightBeneHeight) {
        $(".beneRight").height(leftBeneHeight);
    }   else {
        $(".beneLeft").height(leftBeneHeight);
    };    

    var leftToolHeight = $(".toolLeft").height();
    var rightToolHeight = $(".toolRight").height();

    if (leftToolHeight > rightToolHeight) {
        $(".toolRight").height(leftToolHeight);
    }   else {
        $(".toolLeft").height(rightToolHeight);
    };

</script>
```

Sorry couldn't provide a fiddle as this also pull from a private API.

Comment: In addition, why can't I just use height: inherit;? Both of these have parent divs!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
lvar leftToolHeight = $('.toolLeft').height();
var rightToolHeight = $('.toolRight').height();

if (leftToolHeight > rightToolHeight) {
  $('.toolRight').height(leftToolHeight);
} else {
  $('.toolLeft').height(rightToolHeight);
}
```

Do the same thing with beneLeft and beneRight. I hope this helps!

Comment: Because you are dealing with only two elements each, then I would say there is no point of using an each function.

Comment: Makes sense, but not sure why it isn't working. I updated my current code in initial post. Any thoughts?